# After hitting "Power Cycle" on DigitalOcean, the app doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digital-ocean, atg-droplet

I needed to create an image of the current droplet on DigitalOcean, so I powered off the droplet from dashboard, created the new image of the current droplet and then wanted to turn on the droplet again. So I hit "Power Cycle".

The problem is that after 10 minutes, the app is still not up. What happened and, how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What are your precise symptoms? is the digital ocean droplet not up?

Comment: Send them a support request. They're generally very good at responding quickly

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the application may not be configured to start on boot. The power cycle feature at DO is basically just a gentle reboot (it tries to wait for things to shut down instead of deploying more harsh methods to stop the processes). Does the application start up if you SSH in and start it manually? If so, next check on what starts it automatically at boot. It might have encountered an error (environment errors are common) and should have reported somewhere (syslog, application log, etc.).

Just to help you out moving forward, DO supports live snapshots now, so you should be able to snapshot your droplet without powering it off. :)